# Android Progress Dialog while Connecting to database

Tags: android, database, request, progress

I have an android app which requires the user to login. Once logged in, they can check their data they have inputted once before from a database stored on an online.

When the app is making the request and waiting for the results of the SQL query I want to use one of the android progress wheels saying "loading..." or some other message, however I have failed to understand how to do this wherever I look.

The code basically makes a HTTP request and then waits for a response. Once the response has been returned ("accepted" or "declined" for login details) the app then knows if the person inputted correct details or not. If they have, it takes them to the main menu, else it says its an invalid username or password.

How would I go about adding a progress wheel while this is happening?

Thanks
Tom

Comment: look at the async task examples. You start your progress dialog on preExecute method and finish it on postExecute method

Comment: here is a great place to start: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html